# Non-glass options for custom shower door

Tags: bathroom, shower, glass, sliding-glass-door

I have an unfinished neo-angle shower enclosure (see dimensions below). The tile is in, but there is no door or glass panel. This is a bathroom in the basement, so I don't want to spend $3k on a frameless setup.

What is the next cheapest option above a shower-rod? Is there a non-glass option?

I recently stayed at a hotel, where the shower was enclosed in some acrylic-like material. It was definitely not glass, as the door was very light. At the same time, it looked quite nice and didn't feel cheap.

In any case, I'll appreciate any ideas whatsoever!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Polycarbonate is used in many industrial machines I used to work on. It is like a very strong alternative to acrylic, it doesn't shatter easily and can be gotten in a good clear grade. More expensive than acrylic but alot tougher

It was used for windows on oil reservoirs and for interlocked guards on production lines where you could see the product through the clear polycarbonate and then i
Access if required. The staff were a nightmare for treating things like sh*t and you always knew an acrylic sheet from a polycarb one because acrylic ones were always cracked.

Comment: I just did some digging and found people actually do use polycarbonate and acrylic for shower doors so you'd just have to weigh up the pros and cons. Polycarbonate won't crack or shatter but is more expensive and will scratch easier. Acrylic is cheaper and harder so wont scratch easy but will crack if you abuse it.